# How do I make my player speed up when collide with a game object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I am doing a school project in Unity. My team and I decided to make an endless runner 2D game. However, because it is the first time I use C#, I don't know how to make my player's  speed accelerate when collide with a game object in Unity. I only know how to destroy the player's health when a collision happens. Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: Provide us with some more information. How does the player class look like. Basically give us an example to work with, thanks.

Comment: Please provide details on how you move your player. Otherwise it is impossible to tell how you can accelarite the movement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) , take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, input, obtained and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

it's quite hard to give answers without seeing any code you've written, but as it's 2D and you've already got the collision damage working, you've probably used an `OnCollisionEnter()`, well it's very similar: you test if you've collided (which you've already done), then you add force to your player using a rigidbody2d, probably something along the lines of:

```
public Rigidbody2D rb;

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    rb.AddForce(direction * force, ForceMode2D.Impulse); // the ForceMode2D is 
//                                                  optional, it's just so that
//                                              the velocity change is sudden.
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a GameManager that stores the game speed you can also do that too:

```
private float gameSpeedMultiplier = 0.5f;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Tag of the collided object")
    {
        GameManager.Instance.gameSpeed += gameSpeedMultiplier;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PlayerContoler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static PlayerContoler instance;

    public float moveSpeed;
    public Rigidbody2D theRB;
    public float jumpForce;

    private bool isGrounded;
    public Transform GroundCheckPoint;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;

    private bool canDoubleJump;

    private Animator anim;
    private SpriteRenderer theSR;

    public float KnockbackLength, KnockbackForce;
    private float KnockbackCounter;

    public float bonceForce;

    public bool stopImput;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        theSR = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(!PauseMenu.instance.isPause && !stopImput)
        {
            if (KnockbackCounter <= 0)
            {

             theRB.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), theRB.velocity.y);

             isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(GroundCheckPoint.position, .2f, whatIsGround);

             if (isGrounded)
             {
                 canDoubleJump = true;
             }

             if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
             {
                 if (isGrounded)
                 {
                    theRB.velocity = new Vector2(theRB.velocity.x, jumpForce);
                     AudioManager.instance.PlaySFX(10);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     if (canDoubleJump)
                     {
                        theRB.velocity = new Vector2(theRB.velocity.x, jumpForce);
                        canDoubleJump = false;
                         AudioManager.instance.PlaySFX(10);
                     }
                }
            }

            if (theRB.velocity.x < 0)
            {
                theSR.flipX = true;
            }
            else if (theRB.velocity.x > 0)
            {
                theSR.flipX = false;
            }
        } else
        {
            KnockbackCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
            if(!theSR.flipX)
            {
                theRB.velocity = new Vector2(-KnockbackForce, theRB.velocity.y);
            } else
            {
                theRB.velocity = new Vector2(KnockbackForce, theRB.velocity.y);
            }
        }

     }

        anim.SetFloat("moveSpeed", Mathf.Abs(theRB.velocity.x));
        anim.SetBool("isGrounded", isGrounded);
    }

    public void Knockback()
    {
        KnockbackCounter = KnockbackLength;
        theRB.velocity = new Vector2(0f, KnockbackForce);

        anim.SetTrigger("hurt");
    }
}
```

Comment: 2d platfomer code, there is some that is not endlessRunner.